# Run a pytest test flow with differest starting data while running each test case

Tags: python, pytest

basically if I have test cases written like

```
class TestClass:
    data = "a"
    def test_1(self):
        TestClass.results = function1(TestClass.data)
    def test_2(self):
        function1(TestClass.results[1])
    def test_3(self):
        function1(TestClass.results[2])
    def test_4(self):
        function1(TestClass.results[3])
```

and i want to execute all 4 test cases, multiple times with multiple scenarios, in this case by changing "data" variable. how can I do it simply without copy pasting the whole class?

the main goal is to run and log 8 cases in case of 2 flows 12 in case of 3 and etc. (i want to control which test case gets the data and which doesnt)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@pytest.mark.parametrize` in class level

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('data', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
class TestClass:

    def test_1(self, data):
        function1(data)

    def test_2(self, data):
        function1(data)

    def test_3(self, data):
        function1(data)

    def test_4(self, data):
        function1(data)
```

Output

```
example_test.py::TestClass::test_1[a] PASSED                             [  8%]
example_test.py::TestClass::test_1[b] PASSED                             [ 16%]
example_test.py::TestClass::test_1[c] PASSED                             [ 25%]
example_test.py::TestClass::test_2[a] PASSED                             [ 33%]
example_test.py::TestClass::test_2[b] PASSED                             [ 41%]
example_test.py::TestClass::test_2[c] PASSED                             [ 50%]
example_test.py::TestClass::test_3[a] PASSED                             [ 58%]
example_test.py::TestClass::test_3[b] PASSED                             [ 66%]
example_test.py::TestClass::test_3[c] PASSED                             [ 75%]
example_test.py::TestClass::test_4[a] PASSED                             [ 83%]
example_test.py::TestClass::test_4[b] PASSED                             [ 91%]
example_test.py::TestClass::test_4[c] PASSED                             [100%]
```

Comment: damn i didnt know i could use parametrize with classes as well!

Comment: can you also give me an example with combinations? like case 1 "data1 = 1 and data2 = 2", case2 "data1= 2 and data2= 2"

Comment: also this doesnt really solve my problem, as in most of the cases i dont need to pass those parametrize variables to all the test cases. editted the question accordingly.

Comment: @Saba I'm not sure I understand, but if you want to control combinations you can create a function that `yields` the combinations and run it in `parametrize`, `@pytest.mark.parametrize('data',  get_data())`.

Comment: @Saba well that what you asked. To send different parameters to every test you need to use `@pytest.mark.parametrize` on each one separately, you can't control it that way.

Comment: If you're looking for a way to set up every possible combination of tests given two arrays of input, you can simply add a second parametrize decorator and it'll run through each permutation